# "Before doing X or doing Y, you need to do Z", does it mean Z, X/Y, Z, X/Y OR Z, X/Y, X/Y, X/Y?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> While camping, you plan to fry some eggs and steam some fishes. Before
> actually frying an egg or steaming a fish, you need to check that the
> fire is still burning.

Which of the following does the paragraph above mean? Is the description so ambiguous that you can't tell either way?

> Interpretation 1:
>
> 1. Check fire
> 2. Fry a egg or steam a fish
> 3. Check fire
> 4. Fry a egg or steam a fish
> 5. Check fire
> 6. Fry a egg or steam a fish
>
> Interpretation 2:
>
> 1. Check fire
> 2. Fry the eggs or steam the fishes, in whichever order you prefer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your example is intended to be a realistic and natural use of language, where philosophical precision is not called for, I would understand the sentence that begins "Before actually frying..." to mean that, before doing either of those things, one must check to make sure the fire is still burning. But it's not a mutually exclusive scenario. The fire-check applies equally to both, regardless of the order in which they occur, and whether they occur singly or together.

> If you have been digging in the garden, you should wash your hands
>   before you put on your contact lenses or brush your teeth.

Answer (score 0):

*Before actually frying an egg **or** steaming a fish, you need to check that the fire is still burning.*

In this sentence as it stands, you first check that the fire is still burning. The second action can be one of two possibilities: :

1. Frying an egg
2. Steaming a fish.

The *or* in your original statement  precludes the possibility of both frying an egg **and** steaming a fish.

Answer (score 0):

As TRomano explains, "or" in English usually means "and/or", not "exclusive or" ("xor").

Answer (score 0):

The sentence could be interpreted either way. Actually it could be interpreted at least 3 ways:

First do Z, then do either X or Y. If you want to do both X and Y, you must do Z twice, once before each.

First do Z, then do X or Y or both.

First do Z, then do either X or Y. You cannot do both X and Y.

For example:

"Before driving the car to the store or to school, check the oil." If the person is going to the store and from there to school, he probably doesn't need to check the oil twice.

"Before driving the car to the store or to school, check if you have enough gas." You might need to recheck before each trip.

"Before driving the car over a cliff or into the lake, be sure you can get out before it's too late." He can only do one or the other, because after that the car is destroyed.

It all depends on the type of action you're describing.

If you don't think the interpretation will be clear to the reader, add additional words to make it explicit.

Answer (score 0):

> Which of the following does the paragraph above mean?

I take the sentence as a *joke*. Of course, before cooking the fire must be burning. It is like saying "before taking a bath, you need to check there is water in the bathtub". Or "before cooking a chicken, make sure you have a chicken".

Trying to interpret whether you keep checking if the fire is still burning during the cooking process is taking the entire sentence too literally. That is like saying "whilst taking a bath, keep checking there is still water in the bathtub".